# Numberbox jeasyui not showing value from variable

Tags: javascript, datagrid, jquery-easyui

I have set value to a variable, but when I want to write down the value into numberbox, nothing is happen. I am working  with datagrid jQuery Easyui here is my code

```
function update(){
        var pesan='';
        var dg =$(dgUpholdstery);
        var id_cotation = '<?php echo $id_cotation ?>';

        $.map(dg.datagrid('getChecked'), function(row){
            var index = dg.datagrid('getRowIndex', row);
            var harga=0;
            var mat_waste='0';
            var kode='';

            harga = row.brg_harga;
            mat_waste = row.mat_waste;
            kode = row.material;
            $.ajax({
                type    : 'POST',
                url     : "<?php echo site_url(); ?>/cotation/harga_cotation",
                data    : "kode="+kode+"&type=upholstery",
                dataType    : 'json',
                cache   : false,
                success : function(data){
                    var $response=$(data);
                    if (harga!=$response[0]['harga']){
                        harga = $response[0]['harga'];
                    }
                    if (mat_waste!=$response[0]['mat_waste']){
                        mat_waste = $response[0]['mat_waste'];
                    }
                }
            });
            dg.datagrid('beginEdit',index);

            var ed_mat_waste = dg.datagrid('getEditor', {index:index, field:'mat_waste'});
            var ed_brg_harga = dg.datagrid('getEditor', {index:index, field:'brg_harga'});

            // this is part is not working
            $(ed_mat_waste.target).numberbox('setValue',mat_waste);

            //if I using the code bellow that I comment, it's work fine
            //$(ed_mat_waste.target).numberbox('setValue','35');
            cotation_uphold(index);

            dg.datagrid('endEdit',index);
        });

    }
```

when I test to alert the variable, it's show the value 
if I write direct value, it's working but if I put the variable, it's do nothing

Answer (score 0):

I solved it.
here is the code

```
function update(){
        var pesan='';
        var dg =$(dgUpholdstery);
        var id_cotation = '<?php echo $id_cotation ?>';

        $.map(dg.datagrid('getChecked'), function(row){
            var index = dg.datagrid('getRowIndex', row);

            var harga=0;
            var mat_waste=0;
            var kode='';

            harga = row.brg_harga;
            mat_waste = row.mat_waste;
            kode = row.material;



            $.ajax({
                type    : 'POST',
                url     : "<?php echo site_url(); ?>/cotation/harga_cotation",
                data    : "kode="+kode+"&type=upholstery",
                dataType    : 'json',
                cache   : false,
                success : function(data){
                    var $response=$(data);

                    if (harga!=$response[0]['harga'] && mat_waste!=$response[0]['mat_waste']){
                        dg.datagrid('beginEdit',index);
                        var ed_mat_waste = dg.datagrid('getEditor', {index:index, field:'mat_waste'});
                        var ed_brg_harga = dg.datagrid('getEditor', {index:index, field:'brg_harga'});



                            $(ed_brg_harga.target).numberbox('setValue',$response[0]['harga']);

                            $(ed_mat_waste.target).numberbox('setValue',$response[0]['mat_waste']);

                        cotation_uphold(index);

                        dg.datagrid('endEdit',index);
                    }
                }
            });

        });

    }
```